# Parse Lego Digital Designer *.lxf files

Tags: parsing, lego-mindstorms

I was toying with Lego digital designer the other day (http://ldd.lego.com/) and I was wondering if the saved file could be relatively easily parsed.
As anybody ever done that before? I'm looking for code examples, no matter the language :)

Thanks !

Romain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this would help: http://bricksviewer.sourceforge.net/index.shtml

A .lxf file is just a zip file, on the page I mentioned there is a short description of the format. For more details you should read the source.